# Помогите разобраться с циклом While

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо запустить ввод с клавиатуры значений, пока пользователь не введёт цифру 3 (пример образный, чтобы понять функционал)

```
user = input()
while user!='3':
    if user=='1':
        print('Menu info')
       
    if user=='2':
        print('Off page')
        
break
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы разобрался, нужно действовать так:

```
while True:
    user = input()
    if user=='1':
            print('Menu info')
        
    if user=='2':
            print('Off page')
    if user=='3':    
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = ''
while user != '3':
    user = input('>>')
    if user == '1':
        print('Menu info')
    if user == '2':
        print('Off page')
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретная суть вашего кода, это то, что вам будет выводиться на экран данное сообщение об выборе первого или второго действия, пока не будет введено значение '3'.

Суть цикла while в том, что он будет повторно исполнять его ТЕЛО, пока УСЛОВИЕ будет true.

Если вы и этого не поняли, тогда советую разобраться с условными операторами